# Router repeatedly singling out one Windows 11 machine for DHCP renewal and causing brief network interruptions

Tags: networking, router, windows-11, dhcp, connection

I have a Windows 11 machine which disconnects from the wired network for 5-ish seconds multiple times per day, sometimes multiple times within a few minutes or every 15 minutes or so. It's accompanied by Event 27 "Network link is disconnected".

There are a variety of devices on this network, and only this machine is affected.

I think it's doing some kind of flawed DHCP renewal.

The Nokia 10G PON ONT responsible for DHCP shows this in its logs each time (aquanaut is the host name of the affected PC):

```
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:03.489941+00:00 AONT dhcpd 3064 - -  DHCP-Comm:[check_port_ingress] iftype= ifname=eth4.0 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:03.489969+00:00 AONT dhcpd 3064 - -  Try to read file /configs/etc/dhcpsnoop.conf_orig contents and look for interface eth4.0! 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:03.490011+00:00 AONT dhcpd 3064 - -  read_gre_config: Read file /configs/etc/dhcpsnoop.conf_orig with data  
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:03.490027+00:00 AONT dhcpd 3064 - -  option_82=1 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:03.490043+00:00 AONT dhcpd 3064 - -  option_60=1 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:03.490058+00:00 AONT dhcpd 3064 - -  service_id= 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:03.490073+00:00 AONT dhcpd 3064 - -  cktid_format=1 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:03.490087+00:00 AONT dhcpd 3064 - -  rmtid_format=1 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:03.490109+00:00 AONT dhcpd 3064 - -  Contents of file /configs/etc/dhcpsnoop.conf_orig 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:03.490124+00:00 AONT dhcpd 3064 - -  option_82=1 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:03.490139+00:00 AONT dhcpd 3064 - -  option_60=1 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:03.503694+00:00 AONT dhcpd 3064 - -  service_id= 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:03.503722+00:00 AONT dhcpd 3064 - -  cktid_format=1 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:03.503738+00:00 AONT dhcpd 3064 - -  rmtid_format=1 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:03.504463+00:00 AONT dhcpd 3064 - -  DHCP-Comm:sendACK() the Host-Name:aquanautQ#013 length:[8]. 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:03.504492+00:00 AONT dhcpd 3064 - -  DHCP-Comm:create_or_update_lease() MAC:ADDRESS:REDACTED ip(8101a8c0),portid=0, addrServPool default, lease=86400. 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:03.571871+00:00 AONT dhcpd 3064 - -  DHCP-Comm:dealRequestMessage() Deal Dhcp-RequestMessage Success! DHCP request port-0, MAC:ADDRESS:REDACTED RequestIP-0 XID-14ea467b 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:33.613828+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  DHCP-Comm:send_renew() Unicasts a DHCP renew message 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:29:35.655079+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  dhcpc:mask=0,ip=0.0.0.0,mask=0.0.0.0,tftpserver=0.0.0.0, 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:32:03.728847+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  DHCP-Comm:send_renew() Unicasts a DHCP renew message 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:32:05.775116+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  dhcpc:mask=0,ip=0.0.0.0,mask=0.0.0.0,tftpserver=0.0.0.0, 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:34:33.843828+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  DHCP-Comm:send_renew() Unicasts a DHCP renew message 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:34:35.890088+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  dhcpc:mask=0,ip=0.0.0.0,mask=0.0.0.0,tftpserver=0.0.0.0, 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:34:45.063829+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4329 - -  DHCP-Comm:send_renew() Unicasts a DHCP renew message 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:34:47.105269+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4329 - -  dhcpc:mask=100000,ip=0.0.0.0,mask=0.0.0.0,tftpserver=0.0.0.0, 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:37:03.958833+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  DHCP-Comm:send_renew() Unicasts a DHCP renew message 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:37:06.005104+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  dhcpc:mask=0,ip=0.0.0.0,mask=0.0.0.0,tftpserver=0.0.0.0, 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:39:34.068833+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  DHCP-Comm:send_renew() Unicasts a DHCP renew message 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:39:36.110075+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  dhcpc:mask=0,ip=0.0.0.0,mask=0.0.0.0,tftpserver=0.0.0.0, 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:42:04.183835+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  DHCP-Comm:send_renew() Unicasts a DHCP renew message 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:42:06.235023+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  dhcpc:mask=0,ip=0.0.0.0,mask=0.0.0.0,tftpserver=0.0.0.0, 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:44:34.298833+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  DHCP-Comm:send_renew() Unicasts a DHCP renew message 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:44:36.340118+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  dhcpc:mask=0,ip=0.0.0.0,mask=0.0.0.0,tftpserver=0.0.0.0, 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:47:04.413838+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  DHCP-Comm:send_renew() Unicasts a DHCP renew message 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:47:06.465075+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  dhcpc:mask=0,ip=0.0.0.0,mask=0.0.0.0,tftpserver=0.0.0.0, 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:49:34.523829+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  DHCP-Comm:send_renew() Unicasts a DHCP renew message 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:49:36.575100+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  dhcpc:mask=0,ip=0.0.0.0,mask=0.0.0.0,tftpserver=0.0.0.0, 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:52:04.638830+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  DHCP-Comm:send_renew() Unicasts a DHCP renew message 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:52:06.685968+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  dhcpc:mask=0,ip=0.0.0.0,mask=0.0.0.0,tftpserver=0.0.0.0, 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:54:34.748836+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  DHCP-Comm:send_renew() Unicasts a DHCP renew message 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:54:36.795056+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4317 - -  dhcpc:mask=0,ip=0.0.0.0,mask=0.0.0.0,tftpserver=0.0.0.0, 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:54:45.178837+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4329 - -  DHCP-Comm:send_renew() Unicasts a DHCP renew message 
[notice] <133>1 2023-12-25T21:54:47.234959+00:00 AONT dhcpc 4329 - -  dhcpc:mask=100000,ip=0.0.0.0,mask=0.0.0.0,tftpserver=0.0.0.0,
```

I have tried 3 different NIC's (the onboard one, a PCIE one, and a USB one, with chipsets from different manufacturers. It has made no difference. I've tried disabling all third-party software, and even reinstalled windows. I've also tried removing all other devices from the network and replacing the network cable. No difference.

EDIT: This turned out to be a faulty cable routing ethernet inside the PC itself (the form-factor of the case meant that the NIC itself was not exposed directly at the back of the case, but rather reached there via a small extension cable). The DHCP logs were a red herring, and were a symptom of the issue, rather than the cause of the issue.

Comment: If it's wired, have you tried a known-good ethernet cable? If it's wireless, have you checked the signal strength the client machine is showing on the router's WebUI?

Comment: @JW0914 It's wired and I have tried known good cables.

Comment: Have you check NIC drivers in WIndows ? - A good test would be to fix (static mode) the IP address in Windows instead of use DHCP. If there is no disconnection, you can assume that issue comes from your DHCP server. - Another test to do would be to install a new System (other than Windows) and see the behavior.

Comment: @user1875116 I have tried 3 physically different NIC devices, which are different brands, therefore obviously different drivers. I have tried static IP and it still happens.

Comment: Are you setting the static IP on the machine or the router? It should be done on the router, with the machine still configured for DHCP; doing so requires a non-privatized MAC on the machine _(e.g. the actual adapter MAC needs to be used)_. If the static IP was set on the router and not the machine, if you configure the machine with a static IP, using the DHCP IP, does it still occur? Please boot up a Linux live USB, such as an Ubuntu install USB _(choosing to "Try Ubuntu")_ - does the issue still occur? If not, it would point to something misconfigured in Windows - perform a repair install.